# compare number of days with value

Tags: python, pandas, days

I work with dataset below named "emails_visits"

```
      Territory Account: External ID                Date  Clicked  Opened  Sent       Call Method date_after date_before days_before_visit  days_after_visit
40582     PsAPS4         WNLN03239383 2021-02-16 13:46:00      0.0     0.0   1.0               RTE        NaT         NaT               NaT               NaT
19726  CardioPS5         WNLN00441144 2021-09-17 13:33:00      0.0     0.0   1.0               RTE        NaT         NaT               NaT               NaT
3532       ASPS4         WNLN00026136 2021-10-25 17:02:00      0.0     0.0   1.0               RTE 2021-10-21         NaT               NaT   4 days 17:02:00
22371  CardioPS6         WNLN04438596 2021-06-15 13:44:00      0.0     1.0   1.0               RTE        NaT         NaT               NaT               NaT
35930     PSOPS5         WNLN02913837 2021-08-19 09:59:00      0.0     1.0   1.0               RTE        NaT         NaT               NaT               NaT
40099     PsAPS3         WNLN09365001 2021-02-25 16:18:00      0.0     0.0   1.0               RTE 2020-05-12         NaT               NaT 289 days 16:18:00
25013  CardioPS7         WNLN04585438 2021-05-31 14:45:00      0.0     1.0   1.0               RTE        NaT  2021-06-22  21 days 09:15:00               NaT
60381   MEDRESP6         WNLN00000715 2021-03-02 00:00:00      NaN     NaN   NaN  Virtual MS Teams 2021-03-02  2021-03-02   0 days 00:00:00   0 days 00:00:00
```

I want to create new column with time brackets, for example if value <3 days time bracket is `[3]`
I used
`emails_visits["before_bracket"]=emails_visits.apply(lambda x:"[3]"if x[10]<3 else "[10]" if x[10]<10 days else "[10+]")`

I receive an error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I`ve also tried to convert column to numeric using `emails_visits["days_before_visit"]=pd.to_numeric(emails_visits["days_before_visit"])`
but got some weird numbers like -9223372036854775808 or 1433520000000000

Comment: It's an issue with the `x[10]<3` and `x[10]<10`. Hint: show us what the output is if you do `emails_visits.apply(lambda x: x[10])`

Comment: It is ```NaN``` everywhere but column has been created

Comment: Can you please share the `email_visits` column?

Comment: ```email_visits``` is the name of dataset, I updated topic and showed few rows of it

Comment: @Maksim.Levin is your day_before_visit column containing values of this type: "21 days 09:15:00", what would that mean, 21 days ago, at 09:15:00 ?

Comment: @MiTriPy this column is the difference ```emails_visits["days_before_visit"]=emails_visits["date_before"]-emails_visits["Date"]``` I calculated time between visit and email sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more cleaner and faster way would be to use `np.select` with conditions and values

```
import numpy as np


days_after_visit = emails_visits["days_after_visit"].dt.days

conditions = [
    days_after_visit < 3,
    days_after_visit < 10,
    days_after_visit >= 10
]

values = [
    "[3]",
    "[10]",
    "[10+]"
]

emails_visits["before_bracket"] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dtype of the `days_after_visit` column to be timedelta64[ns],
you can use the `dt.days` accessor to extract the number of days:

```
emails_visits["before_bracket"] = emails_visits['days_after_visit'].dt.days.apply(
    lambda x: "[3]" if x<3 else "[10]" if x<10 else "[10+]")
```

It gives:

```
       Territory Account: External ID  ...  days_after_visit  before_bracket
40582     PsAPS4         WNLN03239383  ...               NaT           [10+]
19726  CardioPS5         WNLN00441144  ...               NaT           [10+]
3532       ASPS4         WNLN00026136  ...   4 days 17:02:00            [10]
22371  CardioPS6         WNLN04438596  ...               NaT           [10+]
35930     PSOPS5         WNLN02913837  ...               NaT           [10+]
40099     PsAPS3         WNLN09365001  ... 289 days 16:18:00           [10+]
25013  CardioPS7         WNLN04585438  ...               NaT           [10+]
60381   MEDRESP6         WNLN00000715  ...   0 days 00:00:00             [3]
```

---

If the column only contain strings, you can convert it to timedelta with:

```
emails_visits['days_after_visit'] = pd.to_timedelta(emails_visits['days_after_visit'])
```